# three rotation can't effect

Tags: three.js, camera, rotation

I used OrbitControls in my Program. I can't use lookAt to set my camera view direction, just used controls.target. It effect some error. Now I have to used ramera.rotation set camera direction, but it not work.

```
console.log(camera.rotation)
camera.rotation.setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(-9,1,1))
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
console.log(camera.rotation)
```

I think controls will reset value of camera.rotation

Comment: Try `controls.enabled = false; camera.rotation.set( x, y, z );`